# How do waitpid and ptrace work together?

Tags: linux-kernel

Going through the source code of Linux 4.12, I can't wrap my head around the below code when task is being **ptraced**.

```
do_wait()
```

will call

```
ptrace_do_wait(wo, tsk)
```

which will call

```
wait_consider_task
```

for every thread that it is tracing on. This will in turn call

```
wait_task_stopped
```

which will then find the PID `[pid = task_pid_vnr(p);]` which is what **waitpid** will return, this is great.

But then it calls

```
put_task_struct(p);
```

which will free the task structure. If that happens, then how does debugger wait on this process/task again? Is this entry added again somewhere, and if so where?

Can any one explain this flow to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "put_task_struct frees the structure"? are you familiar with reference counting? did you see the matching get_task_struct?

let's have a look at the code:

```
get_task_struct(p);
```

refcount incremented

```
pid = task_pid_vnr(p);
why = ptrace ? CLD_TRAPPED : CLD_STOPPED;
read_unlock(&tasklist_lock);
```

the list of all tasks is now unlocked. in principle someone can wait() on the thread get rid of everything but the structure itself due to increased refcount

```
sched_annotate_sleep();
if (wo->wo_rusage)
        getrusage(p, RUSAGE_BOTH, wo->wo_rusage);
put_task_struct(p);
```

... and the refcount is decremented. if this was the last ref, the object is freed. otherwise nothing happens.